# Which data structure should I use for store a UML parameters of methods in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to make a UML Diagramming tool to store parameters of methods:

One thing I can come up with is(In Ruby):

```
["method1" => [{"param1" => "foo"}, {"param2" => "bar"}], "method2" => [{"param1" => "foo"}, {"param2" => "bar"}] ]
```

Does it the right solution?(I noticed each hash only have one key, value pair, which may not efficiency )

If so how to do the same thing in Java?

Answer (score 1):

In java, it'd be idiomatic to make a class named Method.  This class would have a List of Parameters.  And your class would have a List of Methods.  Like so:

```
private class Method {
    private List<Variable> parameters;
    private Type returnType;
}

private class Variable {
    private Type type;
    private String name;
}

private class Type {
    private String name;
}
```

And your `Class` would probably have a List of Methods.  Each one of these would have an equals() and a hashcode().

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer I think if you decide to make a Method class, you also need to make Property class, Constant Class etc. I think a simple key, value and array will do the job

Comment: @yozloy Since you are doing a URL diagram, there is a lot more information required, like private vs public, static vs instance, abstract, etc. Making classes for each of these is probably better in the long run.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes you can right! I already have a class of "Class" that have methods properties something, I just not sure it's a good idea to make another class of methods to store a simple key value store

Comment: @yozloy This is a reply to your first comment: Yes, it will *do the job*, but it's not idiomatic.